# Registration iOS device in APN with Phonegap

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-pushplugin

I'm trying to register an iOS device (iPhone 6s) in APN for send push notifications. I'm using PhoneGap for develop and Adobe PhoneGap for compile the code and get the .ipa. I'm using phonegap-plugin-push.

When I use the init function I never receive the registration event, simply using the example template code for this plugin.

I asume that the Apple certificates are correctly configured: development, push service and provisioning certificates and an App ID with push notifications enabled.

So... I don't know what is wrong but I can't get the device token or simply see the prompt asking for allow push notifications in the app.

Here is the code I'm using (from the template phonegap-template-push):

```
var app = {
    // Application Constructor
    initialize: function() {
        window.alert('calling bindEvents');
        this.bindEvents();
    },
    // Bind Event Listeners
    //
    // Bind any events that are required on startup. Common events are:
    // 'load', 'deviceready', 'offline', and 'online'.
    bindEvents: function() {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
    },
    // deviceready Event Handler
    //
    // The scope of 'this' is the event. In order to call the 'receivedEvent'
    // function, we must explicitly call 'app.receivedEvent(...);'
    onDeviceReady: function() {
        window.alert('Received Device Ready Event');
        window.alert('calling setup push');
        try{
            app.setupPush();
        }
        catch(err){
            window.alert(err.message);
        }
        window.alert('Ready');
    },
    setupPush: function() {
        window.alert('calling push init');
        var push = PushNotification.init({
            "android": {
                "senderID": "12345679"
            },
            "ios": {
                "sound": true,
                "vibration": true,
                "badge": true
            },
            "windows": {}
        });
        window.alert('after init');

        push.on('registration', function(data) {
            window.alert('registration event: ' + data.registrationId);

            var oldRegId = localStorage.getItem('registrationId');
            if (oldRegId !== data.registrationId) {
                // Save new registration ID
                localStorage.setItem('registrationId', data.registrationId);
                // Post registrationId to your app server as the value has changed
            }

            var parentElement = document.getElementById('registration');
            var listeningElement = parentElement.querySelector('.waiting');
            var receivedElement = parentElement.querySelector('.received');

            listeningElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
            receivedElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:block;');
        });

        push.on('error', function(e) {
            window.alert("push error = " + e.message);
        });

        push.on('notification', function(data) {
            window.alert('notification event');
            navigator.notification.alert(
                data.message,         // message
                null,                 // callback
                data.title,           // title
                'Ok'                  // buttonName
            );
       });
    }
};
```

Comment: Some code would be great.

Comment: Is your phone connected to the internet? (also I agree with hva.narola, where is the code)

Comment: Did you register on the 'error' event? Did that give you any feedback? Are there any other errors in you console on iOS when debugging with xCode?

Comment: @hva.narola added ;)

Comment: @nyluje yep, it's connected

Comment: @Ricconnect how can I register the errors using Phonegap? I'm not using xCode

Comment: Change `app.setupPush();` to `this.setupPush();`

Comment: @hva.narola nothing :(

Comment: debug each function where problem is arising? console something in every function so that problem can be found and also add `try-catch` block so that we can know error.

Comment: @hva.narola ok, I did it and I know where is the problem. I receive "Can't find variable PushNotification" using catch-try in app.setupPush()

Comment: Check if plugin and other id are defined in `config.xml` file.

Comment: @hva.narola yep: `<plugin name="phonegap-plugin-push" source="npm" spec="~1.6.2">
        <variable name="SENDER_ID" value="XXXXXXX" />
    </plugin>`

Comment: Change `spec="~1.6.2"` to `spec="1.5.3"` and try again. Ref : https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/issues/779

Comment: @hva.narola ok, with this last change, the error about the variable PushNotification is fixed but I'm not still receiving the event on registration with the token (neither the event on error)

Comment: And the prompt to the user to allow push notifications don't appear

Comment: Then i will have to take a look at source again. :)

Comment: @hva.narola thank you! I've updated the code which I'm using. I receive all the alerts until "after init". Nothing more.

Comment: try to wrap code of `setupPush` method in `try-catch`.

Comment: @hva.narola I think you didn't see the last version of the code. The setupPush is in try-catch already and seems to work properly because the next alert I receive after 'calling setup push' is 'Ready'.

Comment: I mean not function where its being called but i asked for definition.

Comment: @hva.narola do you mean in this way?

`setupPush: function() {
        try{
            window.alert('calling push init');
            var push = PushNotification.init({
                ...
        }
        catch(err){
            window.alert(err.message);
        }`

The result is the same: no error messages :(